# Worklight 6.2 - Push Notification - Is it possible to change userSubscription.userId?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 6.2 trying to get push notification working for our app.

Our app uses adaptor based authentication.

User can navigate the app's first couple pages without logging in.

The problem I encounter is that after user logging in, the userId in userSubscription is not the userId listed for the device under Device tab in Worklight console.

---

Some investigation I did...

After app starts, I can see GCM handle registration log. 
I can receive broadcast notification at this point.

Then, I trigger registerEventSourceCallback.

From the adaptor server log, I see the userId in userSubscription is 
"userId": "1856115d-e9e5-4f9c-8a16-05e58399ee90". This is consistent everytime unless I reinstall the app. I guess this is the persistence cookie id?

I verified I can send/receive unicast notification using the userId above but not my customer user id.

I wonder what's the difference between my app (adaptor based auth) and the demo app (app based auth) in terms of the push notification subscription?

Is there some thing wrong with my login steps that's causing the subscription to use the persistence cookie userId?

Any hint appreciated.

---

Update...

I can achieve unicast by registering eventsourcecallback and subscribe (i don't know how to get the userId any other way). And the userId is the long randomly generated id. Adaptor method used is submitNotification(userId, notificationText) from demo app.

For the correct unicast steps (I think), I am able to use   WL.Server.sendMessage() with notification.target = {userIds: [the-long-userId]}. From the worklight console, before logging in, the UserId column for the device is empty. After logging in, the UserId column is correctly populated with my dummy userId (123_456). However, after post log in, trying to send unicast with userId 123_456 returns "No devices found" in server log.

How can I update the subscription userId post-login? So I can just use the default behavior of unicast instead of subscribing to an event source.

Comment: You mention broadcast and unicast, and then you mention eventsourcecallback. There is no relation between those... are you also trying to implement event source-based notifications in addition to broadcast? broadcast does not require authentication...

Comment: I would like to have all 3 (broadcast, unicast, event source) if possible.

Comment: Please edit your question and keep only the information the is actually relevant to the question.

Comment: sorry got cut off editing the question.

1. Broadcast works pre/post-login as is. That's fine.
2. Unicast works after i register eventsourcecallback only (I have different handler for it) pre/post login. And the userId is the long randomly generated id.
3. Eventsource push works after eventSourceCallback registered and subscribe action.

I would hope to get 2 working first... so the question is... How can I update the subscription userId post-login? I don't want to create a new subscription because that means I will get same broadcast message twice.

Comment: Did some investigation around updating the userId ... The userId won't update unless the device unregisters and registers again with the new userId. The form based login in the Push Hybrid sample (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/) let's u specify the userId.

Comment: We are using challengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication() not challengeHandler.submitLoginForm().... So there is no way to update userId?

How do you unregister the device for push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... Figured out the problem.

The problem was I created an event source in my adaptor without specifying a security test.

After including securityTest in WL.Server.createEventSource(), the userId field of the subscription table is correctly updated from the randomly generated one to my logged in userId.